# What is a .webp file?

Tags: file-format, image-compression

I am accustomed to using old file formats. For example,

- [`.JPEG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)
- [`.BMP`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/bmp)
- [`.GIF`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/gif)

Beginning in the year 2022, I began seeing files having a suffix `.webp`, but I have no idea what a `.webp` is. Maybe `webp` is a sub-sequence formed by deleting one or more letters from the string of text "web page". However, all of the `.webp` files I see do not have any working hyperlinks, or anything dynamic. The `.webp` files seem to be static images, which do not move, just like an old `.jpeg`.

What is a `.webp` file?

Comment: Have you tried entering "webp" into your favorite search engine?

Comment: A user with 4.3k on StackOverflow asks what is a .webp file? 

Comment: Actually WebP (web pictures) can also be animations (like GIF) but there is a sibling format (WebM, web movies) for short videos.

Comment: Not all computer imaging apps know **webp**, but one that does is [paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/) and if you don't want to actually use it (I find in non-intuitive) you can save as a format you are familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

> WebP is a raster graphics file format developed by Google intended as
> a replacement for JPEG, PNG, and GIF file formats. It supports both
> lossy and lossless compression,[8] as well as animation and alpha
> transparency.
>
> Google announced the WebP format in September 2010, and released the
> first stable version of its supporting library in April 2018.

(source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP )